# RegEx - match all sentences contains 20 characters or more between specific tags

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to extract all sentences contains 20 characters or more from longer text, but I'm far from the solution at the moment (RegEx flavor - PCRE)

Example text (I need 'bolded' sentences):

> Tylko u nas! **Kurtka wiatrówka sportowa**. Posiada podszewkę. **Przeznaczona do biegania**. Kup teraz!

My regex at the moment:

```
(^|\.\s)(.{20,}?[a-z])(\!|\.\s|\.$|$)
```

Comment: Format your question..

Comment: I'm closing this question as unclear what you are asking, since you are asking us to solve a natural language problem, which would require extensive research to weed out the special cases.

Comment: Regex can't process language !

Answer (score 1):

```
[^.!><]{20,}
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vR4fY4/16

Comment: Works pretty nice, but not exactly what I'm looking for - in this sentence it doesn't work http://rubular.com/r/Rb6KSXuY1Q

Not every period is an end of the sentence

Comment: @user3310085 So how you define end of a sentence?!

Comment: Something like this, but more sophisticated would be useful:

http://rubular.com/r/ukm0pWrrX6

Group 1 matches my sentences but doesn't reject sentences shorter than 20 characters